# Google Maps JS API v3 - Simple Multiple Marker V2

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using the information on the question at [Google Maps JS API v3 - Simple Multiple Marker Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059044/google-maps-js-api-v3-simple-multiple-marker-example?answertab=active#tab-top)

I'll report it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head> 
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 
  <title>Google Maps Multiple Markers</title> 
  <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" 
          type="text/javascript"></script>
</head> 
<body>
  <div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;"></div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var locations = [
      ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
      ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
      ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
      ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
      ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1]
    ];

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 10,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.92, 151.25),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var marker, i;

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
          infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
      })(marker, i));
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

It work but now I want to improve with locations on database.

```
var locations = [

<?php
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($resultqr)){
echo ("
  [".$row[nome].", ".$row[latitudine].", ".$row[longitudine].",],
");
}
?>

];
```

This code work on testpage but not inside the script in variable locations.

Database connect is on other php section outside the script.

Could you help me?

Comment: What does the HTML generated by that PHP look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
echo json_encode(array_values($row));
```

Or, more guaranteed:

```
$arr = array($row['nome'], $row['latitudine'], $row['longitudine]');
echo json_encode($arr);
```

The problem in your hand-crafted js array is missing quotes around the strings.

---

Considering your full PHP code:

```
<?php
$locations = array();
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($resultqr)){
    $locations[] = array($row['nome'], $row['latitudine'], $row['longitudine']);
}
echo 'var locations = ' . json_encode($locations) . ';';
?>
```

Comment: I found solution with little editing of first code but the new PHP full code you posted is better more than mine.

Thanks for the help!